# PC Monitor Being Very Fussy With DVI Cables

Tags: graphics-card, dvi

I have a GTX 670 connected to a "Matrix Neo" 2560x1440 monitor see [here](http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Displays/Achieva-Shimian-27-Monitor-Review-1440p-IPS-Display-Under-350) for a background on the phenomenon that is the "A- 1440 Panels" with interesting names. The reason I mention the specific monitor is because they come with very little processing built in, no on screen menus only one input etc.

I've been running this setup for 2+ years with no issues. Until I had to change my desk setup and move the monitor further from my tower. The DVI cable I have been using is a standard DVI-D Dual Link 1.2M, obviously 1.2M doesn't give you a lot of maneuvering room, so I bought a new 5M cable.

After connecting with the new cable, windows recognises the monitor is connected and the back light on the monitor powers on but the screen stays black. Thinking I had a dud cable I returned it for a new one, same issue. My next thought was that I had been a bit too ambitious with 5M so bought a 3M cable from another supplier, same issue.

My next, next thought is to try a 2M cable, but cant find any information to suggest that 3M is in any way excessive. The only alternative that i can come up with is that I have had the bad luck to get 3 bad cables from 2 different companies (I don't have another DVI monitor I can test with).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Cheers

Comment: Does the original cable still work?  That would help narrow things down a bit.

Comment: Apologies - should have said - yes the original cable works perfectly every time I swap back.

Comment: I see your monitor has nothing but a single DL-DVI input. A, albeit quite costly, option would be to get a DisplayPort/DL-DVI converter. That way, you can minimize the distance the actual DVI signal has to travel.

Answer (score 0):

DVI actually does have some pretty strange length limits.  If you've been buying single-link DVI cables that's your limitation right there since they can only support 1920 x 1200 @ 60Hz.  If you're sure you've gotten a dual-link cable instead, which can support up to 2560 × 1600 @ 60Hz, then the maximum length is about 15 feet so your 5m cable is just a tad over that.  You could buy a signal booster but likely you just need a shorter, dual-link, cable.

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish between single and dual link just by looking at them? The wikipedia page shows single link as having a gap in the center pins (none of my cables do). Could it be possible manufactures make single link's that look like dual links?

Comment: @Mike, manufacturers do all sorts of shady things.  Your cables might have the pins but they might not be connected, or might be using inferior copper alloys in the wiring.

Comment: Okay, cheers for the tip, sounds like the next step is to get a nice reputable dual link. Will get back to you.

Comment: One thing I noticed this time around is that some cables although claiming to be dual link report support for up to about 2000x1500, not the full 2560x1600. Got one that explicitly claims full 2560 this time. Will update when it arrives.

Comment: Apologies Foosh, after posting the question as a guest and then completing registration the site no longer recognises this as my question so I cant mark an answer. Your help definitely led me to the solution though. I bought the name brand cable with explicit support for 1440 and it works fine at 3M, it seems that dual link is a bit of a hazy standard in the cheap cable market. Mike

Comment: Use the 'contact us' link to ask for an account merger